# Click event on DIV triggered while pointer event is captured by another element in Firefox

Tags: pointers, firefox, events, click, pointer-events

I have the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PieterJanVR/b39u4cgr/3/

```
class SliderAppComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      buttonToggle: false
    }

    this.clicked = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        buttonToggle: !this.state.buttonToggle
      });
    };

    this.isPointerDown = false;
    this.onPointerDown = (e) => {
        const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
        currentTarget.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
        this.isPointerDown = true;
    };

    this.onPointerMove = (e) => {
    if (!this.isPointerDown) return;
        const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
        currentTarget.style.transform = `translate(${e.clientX - 70}px)`;
    };

    this.onPointerUp = (e) => {
        const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
        this.isPointerDown = false;
        currentTarget.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="sliderContainer">
          <div className="slider"
             onPointerDown={this.onPointerDown}
             onPointerMove={this.onPointerMove}
             onPointerUp={this.onPointerUp}
             onPointerCancel={this.onPointerUp}>
             SLIDE ME
        </div>
        </div>

        <button
          style={{backgroundColor: this.state.buttonToggle ? "#00feb0" : "#00b0fe"}}
          onClick={this.clicked}>
        A button with a click event!
        </button>

        <div
          className="fake-button"
          style={{backgroundColor: this.state.buttonToggle ? "#00feb0" : "#00b0fe"}}
          onClick={this.clicked}>
        A div with a click event!
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

It displays a 'slide me' div, which slides when dragged and 2 click elements: a button, and a div.

In Chrome, when you click the "slide me", drag the mouse over the 2 click elements and release: nothing happens ✔.

When you do the same in Firefox, the clickable button doesn't get clicked, but the clickable div does ❌!

Is this a bug in Firefox?

---

**Explanation of the example:**

The "slide me" div captures the Pointer events on pointer down, and releases the capture again when the pointer goes up. The two clickable elements just have a plain 'onClick' listener which makes the background change color.

**Some literature:**

The only reference I could find is this github issue of W3C pointer events: https://github.com/w3c/pointerevents/issues/75. Saying

> We talked about this issue and we all agreed to stick to sending click to the first common ancestor of pointerdown and pointerup targets

In my example that should ONLY trigger a click on the app element. Which is does in Chrome, but in Firefox it triggers the click on the ancestor AND the clickable div.